# Using PATCH with Jersey Client API for unit testing

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, http-patch

I am working on a REST API implementation using Jersey. For `PATCH` (partial updates), I have implemented my own custom implementation of `PATCH` since Jersey does not support it.

Now I am trying to figure out how to write functional tests around that implementation. I am using jersey test framework for other methods (`PUT`, `POST`, `GET`, `DELETE`) that has that support available in that framework.

Is there a way where in I can extend jersey test framework implementation to write my functional tests for `PATCH`? 
If not, are there any other test frameworks available that I can use to test my Jersey `PATCH` implementation?

If anyone can provide any examples, that would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your implementation consists of a custom annotation like this

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.ws.rs.HttpMethod;

@HttpMethod("PATCH")
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PATCH {}
```

Trying to do something like this with the `Client`

```
 String response = target.request().method("PATCH", Entity.text("Hello"), String.class);
```

by default is not supported, and will an exception like

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH
```

This is not a problem with the `Client` API directly, but with the lower level Java APIs. Seems to be some security restriction.

With the Client API we can override this by setting a property

- [`HttpUrlConnectionProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/HttpUrlConnectorProvider.html#SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND) to true

In the `JerseyTest`, one way to configure the `Client` is to override `configureClient`, and set the property with the `ClientConfig`. You could just as easily set the property on the `Client` itself, but staying in the spirit of the `JerseyTest` framework (where we don't need to explicitly access the `Client`, the example below will just just override the method

```
public class PatchTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Path("patch")
    public static class PatchResource {
        @PATCH
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        public String getPatch(String request) {
            return "Patched " + request;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureClient(final ClientConfig config) {
        config.property(HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, true);
    }

    @Override
    public Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(PatchResource.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void doPatchTest() {
        WebTarget target = target("patch");
        String response = target.request().method("PATCH", Entity.text("Hello"), String.class);
        Assert.assertEquals("Patched Hello", response);
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just used like this and it worked with out any configuration on the client.
`String response = target.request().method("PATCH", Entity.text("Hello"), String.class);`

Comment: Newest version of JAX-RS supports PATCH now.

Answer (score 4):

To send the `HTTP PATCH` via `JAX RS Client API` without any extra configuration:

```
 client.target("$baseUrl$restUsersUrl/$userId")
                .request("application/json")
                .build("PATCH", Entity.entity(json2Update, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .invoke()
```

Answer (score 3):

Annotation [`@PATCH`](https://jax-rs.github.io/apidocs/2.1/javax/ws/rs/PATCH.html) is now available in JAX-RS 2.1. You can implement this HTTP method on the server side like:

```
@PATCH
public Response updateResource() { ... }
```

As for the client side, you can do something like:

```
Response r = ClientBuilder.newClient()
    .target("http://localhost:8080/patch")
    .request()
    .build("PATCH", Entity.text("patch"))
    .property(HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, true)
    .invoke();
```

Where `SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND` is used to avoid the protocol exception, as indicated by @peeskillet:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH
```

Answer (score -1):

With simple Strings this works for me. But does anyone know how to do this when the Patch method does not accept and return a simple String? See my example below.
The return type in the Response differs from the type of the passed argument. Both of which are not simple types.
Instead of a 200, I always get a 400 and/or the message that it cannot construct the ObjectPatch instance. And I understand that, since it is an interface with only an apply method. But somehow on runtime it manages to construct an AttentionPatchResource object from it anyway. Unfortunately not when using the JerseyTest framework.

```
@PATCH
 @Path("/something")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Consumes({ PatchMediaTypes.APPLICATION_MERGE_PATCH_JSON, PatchMediaTypes.APPLICATION_JSON_PATCH })
    public Response updateAttention( //
            @Parameter(schema = @Schema(implementation = AttentionPatchResource.class)) ObjectPatch patch) {

        Attention attention = attentionService.find();
        AttentionPatchResource patchResource = attentionAdapter.toPatchResource(attention);

        AttentionPatchResource patchedResource = patch.apply(patchResource);
        Attention patchedAttention = attentionAdapter.fromPatchResource(attention, patchedResource);

        AttentionResource resource = attentionAdapter.toResource(patchedAttention);

        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(resource).build();
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking a Question?

Comment: Please create a new question if you have a question and don't answer old posts.

Comment: I already found a solution. Next time I will start a separate question, but I thought it was in essence the same question, that's why I didn't.
As in response to Scrattle. Yes, I am asking a question. There is only one sentence with a question mark in my post, could that be the question? It's ok if you find it unclear though.